# Can the home folder in ubuntu be located as a subfolder of a data partition?

Tags: 14.04

If so, how would this be setup?

I have seen the howto:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

That seems to indicate that /home ia a partition mount, therefore it cannot be a subfolder of another partition mount.

Or is it actually workable to have the home folder as a subfolder within another data partition? I've actually tried it, and it seems to work fine (with usermod -d applied to point user directory to the subfolder location), but the Places menu of Mate still points to /home.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put your home folder wherever you want, it's just an entry in `/etc/passwd` (and maybe `/etc/passwd-` too).

Editing the file(s) directly & moving your home folder yourself might work, or you can use `usermod` and it should do it for you, see `man usermod`:

```
   -d, --home HOME_DIR
       The user's new login directory.

       If the -m option is given, the contents of the current home
       directory will be moved to the new home directory, which is created
       if it does not already exist.
```

You even tried it and it seems to work, if some mate menu's are still using old folders you can change them to the new folders... something like *"find all instances of `/home/oldhome` and change to `/some/newhome`"* might work, `find` / `grep` / `sed` could do that, maybe even this "quick hack":

```
find /some/newhome -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/\/home\/oldhome/\/some\/newhome/g'
```

but that's a separate question...

---

FYI, if you want to **change the default home** "base dir" (the `/home` part) and you'll be using the **`adduser`** program, you can edit the `/etc/adduser.conf` and change the `DHOME=/home` line to whatever you prefer.

If you're using `useradd` (not recommended) it's *supposed* to change the default "base dir" by using `useradd -D -b/newhome` but it's been temperamental in my tests.

Comment: Very complex answer just to say "yes"!  >:) (*and* upvoted)

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, I didn't think "YUUUUUUUUUP! NEXT!" would be very helpful (or friendly). And the data partition sub-folder was a red herring, I think anything that's mounted at boot (or just before the user logs in) can be a "home"

Comment: [rotfl]  You're right!  ;)